# Question on contraction map into the euclidean ball

Tags: contraction-mapping

How to define a map $f$ from $\mathbb R^n$ to the euclidean unit ball in such a way that $f$ is a contraction?
I was thinking about the map that sends $x\to\frac{x}{\|x\|}$, where $\|x\|$ denotes the euclidean norm of $x$, but the image of this map is the sphere $S^{n-1}$, not the whole ball.

Comment: How about $f\equiv 0$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Can you think of a smooth homeomorphism $f$ of ${\mathbb R}$ to a finite interval such that $|f'(x)|\le 1$ for all $x\in {\mathbb R}$?